# How to prevent Chrome lag with multiple scroll bars?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, next.js

I am building an app that needs to support displaying many divs that can be scrolled horizontally on one page. The page works fine when there are less than 5 of those horizontally scrolling divs, but it is very noticeably laggy when there are more than 10+ divs that can scroll horizontally. By laggy, I mean when scrolling through the page, the fps drops below 30.

I know that the lag is caused by the scroll bars because when I set the div to overflow hidden, the lag doesn't happen anymore. Also, I noticed that this only happens on Chrome. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Upon further investigation, I realized that this issue only happens when I have scroll bars show on scroll only. When the scroll bars are always showing, the lag does not occur.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying to figure out what is going on, I decided to add CSS code to always show scroll bar and that seemed to fix the lag entirely. I am guessing this is a bug with Chrome on macOS. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.